# VSCode Chrome Debgugger Extension: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, visual-studio-code

I am trying to leverage VSCode to debug a Meteor app. I have the following configuration in the .vscode/launch.json file:

`{
   "name": "Attach Client",
   "type": "chrome",
   "request": "attach",
   "port": 9222,
   "address": "localhost",
   "sourceMaps": true,
   "diagnosticLogging": true,
   "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "url": "http://localhost:3000/"
 }`

Once the client side code is waiting for user action, I click on "Attach Client" and get the dreaded error in the title.

I have read the long and quite confusing too paragraphs concerning preventing this error in the readme page of the Chrome Debgugger Extension Github page, but:

- Most of it is undefined and unknown jargon to me so I am following the steps without understanding what they mean for the most part
- Nothing seems to get rid of this error message

a) I did execute in my mac terminal:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --rem
ote-debugging-port=9222`

b) I did type `http://localhost:9222` on the chrome address bar and got localhost refused to connect, but I am not sure if this means that there something running at that port or not

c) I also did type `http://localhost:9222/json` and get the same, which according to the readme page means "something is wrong upstream of the extension" but it does not say what could be wrong and how to fix it.

My setup is:

- OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- VSCode 1.7.2
- VSCode Chrome Debugger extension 2.4.1
- Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95

Is there anyone out there who:

- Got around this error message and
- Has experienced significant productivity gains by switching from debugging directly with plain Google Chrome Dev tools to debugging with the VSCode Chrome Debugger extension?

Comment: I'm using it with React, it's preferable for me over Chrome's debugging at least for raw code (missing lots of the additional browser info in Chrome's devtools). try setting `request` to `launch` and remove `port`, and adding `"userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}.chrome"`. That should launch a new instance of chrome instead of trying to attach to the already running one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this the Chrome Debug extension working in VSCode using Attach mode but suddenly was experiencing this error. To fix it I went into Activity Monitor on my Mac and searched for Chrome. There were several unwanted processes running. For each one I selected it and used the Quit button. There were some remaining which would not even force quit so I took note of the PID (process ID) and opened the Terminal and used the following command:

sudo kill -9 99888

You would of course replace 99888 with the PID you noted.
After doing that for all the remaining Chrome processes, VSCode was able to connect to Chrome the next time I launched it in debug mode.